# Summing all the numbers in a matrix revised

Tags: c++, c++builder

Hello I had recently asked a question about how to do the following:

Write a function that sums all the integers in a matrix of integers using the following header:

```
const int SIZE = 4;
double sumMatrix (const double m [] [SIZE] , int rowSize, int columnSize) ;
```

Write a test program that reads a 4-by-4 matrix and displays the sum of all its elements. Heres a sample run:

Enter a 4by4 matrix row by row:

```
1 2 3 4 [Enter]
5 6 7 8 [Enter]
9 10 11 12 [Enter]
13 14 15 16 [Enter]
Sum of the matrix is 136
```

I tried to use all the suggestions I could but the problem maybe that I just need to go back to the basic and learn some basic things I have skipped over, but heres what I have so far. Corrections and solutions, and help in any form would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

int sum(const int a[] [COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN_SIZE; column++)
        {
            total += a[row][column];
        }
    }

    return total;
}
int main()
{
    int m[4][4]=
    {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16}
    };
    cout<< "Sum of the matrix"<< sum(m,4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good but it's a little unclear what you're asking for. Does your program produce the correct output?

Comment: The read part is missing so far I guess...

Comment: I don't understand why the tags other than c++ are on your question.

Comment: What, except for `<iostream>`, is C++ about this question?

Comment: Is this for a school project or other kind of homework?

Answer (score 1):

The read function that you need will look almost the same as your print function:

```
void read(const int a[] [COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN_SIZE; column++)
        {
            cout << "Enter number for [" << row << "][" << column << "]: ";
            cin >> a[row][column];
        }
    }
}
```

(As a footnote: if you can generalise the looping and have one function that you pass 'read' or 'sum' to you're well on your way to being awesome)

**edit:** guess I didn't read the 'row by row' bit of the question. shrug.

Answer (score 0):

Three years later, haha, but you can enter cols elements separating them with spaces and use enter to get elements of other row.

Improving your code. Just see and understand. A didactic program is better than a thousand words :p

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int COLUMN_SIZE = 4;

int sum(const int a[] [COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN_SIZE; column++)
        {
            total += a[row][column];
        }
    }

    return total;
}

void showmatrix(const int a[] [COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize, const char *name)
{
    int row_index, col_index;

    cout<< name << " [" << rowSize << "][" << COLUMN_SIZE << "] =" << endl;

    for(row_index = 0; row_index < rowSize; row_index++)
    {
        for(col_index = 0; col_index < COLUMN_SIZE; col_index++)
        {
            if(col_index == 0)
            {
                if(row_index ==0)
                {
                    cout<< "\t /";
                }
                else if(row_index == rowSize - 1)
                {
                    cout<< "\t \\";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<< "\t|";
                }
            }

            cout<< "\t" << a[row_index][col_index];

            if(col_index == 3)
            {
                if(row_index ==0)
                {
                    cout<< "\t\\";
                }
                else if(row_index == rowSize - 1)
                {
                    cout<< "\t/";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<< "\t |";
                }
            }
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }

    cout<< endl;
}

int main()
{
    int m[4][4]=
    {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16}
    };

    int row_index, col_index;

    cout<< "There is a stored matrix on that program. It is shown below: " << endl << endl;

    showmatrix(m, 4, "Stored_Matrix");

    cout<< "The sum of elements of that stored matrix is: "<< sum(m,4) << endl << endl;

    cout<< "Now, let's enter another 4 x 4 matrix." << endl << endl;
    cout<< "(Note: You can use <space> character to separate column elements or <enter>" << endl;
    cout<< "key to enter a new row.)" << endl;
    cout<< "(Note 2: Really, you can use both to separate each one of the 16 matrix" << endl;
    cout<< "elements, but do not enter more than that or the program will do some error)." << endl << endl;

    for(row_index = 0; row_index < 4; row_index++)
    {
        for(col_index = 0; col_index < 4; col_index++)
        {
            cin>> m[row_index][col_index];
        }
    }

    cout<< endl;

    cout<< "The entered matrix is below:" << endl << endl;

    showmatrix(m, 4, "Entered_Matrix");

    cout<< "The sum of elements of that entered matrix is: "<< sum(m,4) << endl << endl;

    //only to do not close console window on Windows
    cout<< "Program ended." << endl << endl << "Press something to exit.";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can use it on your reborn or after developing a time machine to use that idea on your 2010 homework.

As you use C++ Builder tag for that question, you can create a new console application and copy-paste the code above overwriting generated one. Use F9 to compile and run.